# How to add radio element inside another radio element in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form

I am trying to write a form consist of multiple radio selections like below.

- Radio 1 Option 1

  - Radio 2 Option 1
  - Radio 2 Option 2
- Radio 1 Option 2

  - Radio 3 Option 1
  - Radio 3 Option 2

I am thinking of creating a custom Radio class to redefine the whole structure. But not sure how to write the decorators.

Any helpful hint on how to write this kind of form is very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pavel's post on http://paveldubinin.com/2011/04/zend-form-radio-buttons/, I made it through his way by taking Radio 1 as the StandaloneRadio Element and put Radio 2 and 3 under each option of Radio 1.